# Jobs will not load when copied to new Jenkins server

Tags: jenkins

I followed this [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins#AdministeringJenkins-Moving%2Fcopying%2Frenamingjobs) for moving jobs between Jenkins servers.  After choosing to 'Reload Configuration from Disk' I am finding that the majority of jobs were migrated however a handful of jobs are not presented within the Jenkins dashboard.  Looking at $JENKINS_HOME/jobs, I see directories for jobs which did not load and confirmed the config files are valid XML.  I have looked at the System Log (via the Jenkins GUI) but find nothing pertinent.  Rebooting the machine and reloading configuration from disk does not resolve the problem.

Interestingly, I can see the previous build history for a specific job if I choose to create a new job with the exact same name as a job which will not load.  The config.xml is overwritten when this occurs.  I am hoping to preserve the job configurations without manually recreating them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I chose to investigate by comparing the config.xml content for loaded and unloaded jobs.  I eventually identified the issue:

```
Jobs which used cron syntax similar to H/* (as well as H/[number]) would not load
```

The issue stemmed from the fact that I migrated to a previous release of Jenkins.  This cron functionality was introduced within 1.5.10 via [story Jenkins-17311](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17311).

Removing the noted syntax from config.xml content allowed jobs to load during subsequent 'Reload Configuration from Disk' executions.

Answer (score 4):

For me I found it that I had copied the jobs over with the wrong permissions - once I ran `chown -R jenkins:jenkins $JENKINS_HOME/jobs` it solved the issue for me

Comment: Awesome.. just as any piece of modern software does.. no damn logs if there are no permisions on the damn folder.. thanks for this!

Comment: still relevant to this day :)